# What are some arguments as to why NoSQL databases do not need ACID?

Tags: database, nosql

I'm trying to collect some information about NoSQL databases and I'm very interested in finding the arguments as to why NoSQL doesn't need ACID transactions.  There doesn't seem to be very much information about this on stackoverflow so I thought it would be worth starting a new question.

Comment: The question is not why a database doesn't need transaction. The question is why your project doesn't need transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your USE CASE may or may not require ACID transactions, but your technology choice either supports ACID or it doesn't. If you need super strict ACID, perhaps NOSQL is not a good approach for your use case. But then again, there are varying ACID definitions, as well as definitions for what a transaction is. So to say NOSQL doesn't need ACID really doesn't make sense, but to say it generally doesn't support ACID is true because the general use cases NOSQL was designed to support don't require it.

here's what HBase says about ACID - basically last guy wins on a row/key

http://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html

ACID in a relational database refers to different transaction isolation levels etc etc.

This is a very broad question, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What sort of use cases would you say that it is better to not have ACID?

Comment: In short, heavy write, heavy read, but with very little update and delete. Also, if you're data has sparse fields, NoSQL is good at storing this type of multi-structured data

Answer (score 1):

because NoSQL databases deliberately gave up ACID semantics for performance and scalability.  ACID has a cost, and if you don't need it you can run faster without it.

Comment: good point... high velocity ingest... read mostly optimized is the general use case